# Counting elements in comma-separated string in attribute table in QGIS

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, attribute-table, count, string

One of my column in an attribute table in QGIS is separated by comma (shown by column `"N"`) and I wanted to count elements in it. The column is a text field string.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! It is recommended to [take the tour](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour), and familiarise yourself with [how to ask a good question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) before posting.

In particular, provide evidence that you have researched the problem, examples of what you have already tried, and be specific about what went wrong.

Comment: You only need to count the numbers of `,` per field and add 1.

Comment: @Erik that would return 1 if the field is empty

Comment: Yeah, but I can only work with what OP provides and not make contigencies for every possible exception ;-) @JGH

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use this expression with field calculator: `array_length (string_to_array (N))`

[image]

Comment: I recommend using double quotes `""` for field names, e.g. `"N"`